# Including spaces for input in batch files

Tags: batch-file

I have a small hacking simulation program:

```
@echo off  
cls  
set /p command="Command :/) "  
if "%command%"=="telnet google.com 443" (  
echo Connected !  
) else [do something else]  
pause
```

But it is not working. Instead of spaces, it works fine if I put `_` or `-` something like that

Comment: works perfectly happily for me.

Comment: but it didn't work for me. i had also tried with if /i  but it works on a string "scan [network]" but not the telnet part

Comment: I'd put the `/I` switch to the `if` command to do the comparison case-insensitively; is the code portion part of a block within parenthesis `()`?

Comment: i tried putting /I switch but it fails. actually it works in first command i give it to whatever it may be. but it stops working from second command and further. and sorry i can't get you for your second suggestion i.e. ( )

Answer (score 0):

Although for me your code works perfectly fine, you could try this:

```
@echo off  
cls  
set /p "command=Command :/) "  
if "%command%"=="telnet google.com 443" (  
echo Connected !  
) else [do something else]  
pause
```

note the double quotes around the `set /p` instead of just the message.
Also, **make sure the filename isn't set.bat or something like that**, because it can cause the batch-file to call itself instead of executing a command.

Comment: Thank you first of all for you help,  
 But it didn't work for me. It works in first command whatever it may be, but doesn't work further. Is there any other idea ?

Comment: I'm guessing that means there is more code in the batch-file you're not showing us. You could also try to remove the @echo off, and show us what commands get outputted.

Comment: yes you are right. there is more codes in my batch-file (game or hacking simulation program) that has different commands to function different hacking-like stuff. but i can't show you in this comment box. but as you told, it displays an error message with a variable that i give input to it.but it works fine for first command. are you getting my point ?

Comment: I suggest editing your question to show the full Code below your question

Comment: If you message me when you updaate your question with the full code, and maybe the error message (if you can't see it because it goes away to fast, try starting your code from cmd or press printscreen when it errors) I'll try to continue helping me.

Comment: i would like to post all code but i am having trouble with it. and as you said, it is very difficult to print screen message because it is so fast. is there any other ways ? and thank you for your effort. how can i message you if i want ?